# «Не» или «ни» следует писать в данном предложении?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

*Скоро родители ребят начнут заполнять зал. Учитель же переживал, как бы это **ни** случилось во время выступления Галкиной Маши.*

Все просто: отрицания нет, значит, пишем "ни", верно? Или же есть тут какие-то подводные камни?
Извиняюсь за этот банальный вопрос, но иногда так переклинит, что единственное спасение — спросить совета тут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что имеется в словаре Ефремовой:
[**как бы**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-29238.htm)
**1.** *союз*
3) Употр. при присоединении придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, которая раскрывает содержание главной части; **чтобы**.

В вашем предложении правильно писать **не**:
*Учитель же переживал, как бы это **не** случилось во время выступления Галкиной Маши.*

Конечно же, здесь есть отрицание: как бы = чтобы; случилось = произошло.
Смысл: учитель переживал, чтобы **это** (= заполнение зала) **не** случилось (= не произошло) во время чьего-то выступления.

― Смотрите, мессер Пьетро, **как бы** от этих мыслей у вас у самого душа **не** рассталась с телом. [А. К. Дживелегов. Очерки итальянского Возрождения (1929)]

Answer (score 1):

С "ни" совсем другой смысл, и он не подходит:
*Учитель же переживал независимо от того, как случится во время выступления.*

Как бы **не** = чтобы не (но не наоборот!):
*Учитель же переживал, чтобы это **не** случилось во время выступления Галкиной Маши.*

Более понятный пример с "ни":
*Он работал, как бы ни было трудно.* || Как не было бы трудно.

Ситуации не пересекаются, и из-за этого не удаётся подобрать пример, где были бы корректны оба варианта.

Сравните:
*Он боялся, чтобы не говорили.* || Боялся того, что будут говорить.
*Он боялся, что бы ни говорили.* || Боялся несмотря на всё то, что ему говорили.

**"Ни" обычно ставится в придаточных предложениях при наличии частицы "бы", но в данном примере "как бы" цельное (союз), на что указывает то, что "бы" нельзя переставить. Поэтому "ни" не подходит.**